# Python: initializing method in class

Tags: python, class, tkinter, init

I created a simple program that displays 28 numbers on the screen. Currently, nothing happens when you click on the numbers. Eventually, I want the numbers to disappear on click. Also, when you click on a '5', you get 5 points. I would like to make this multiplayer too where the user with the most points after 10 seconds wins. But that is all for later.

My code is:

```
from Tkinter import *
import random

class Game(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, background="white")
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.title("Centered window")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.centerWindow()

    def centerWindow(self):

        w = 850
        h = 530

        sw = self.parent.winfo_screenwidth()
        sh = self.parent.winfo_screenheight()

        x = (sw - w)/2
        y = (sh - h)/2
        self.parent.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))

def main():

    global tile_frame_column  # the labels that go on the screen of individual numbers
    tile_frame_column = {}

    global tiles_make_number  # dictionary of all the individual numbers
    tiles_make_number = {}

    global tile_frame_column_counter
    tile_frame_column_counter=0  

    global tiles_make_number_counter
    tiles_make_number_counter=0

    global xpos
    xpos=35

    global ypos
    ypos=50

    tile_numbers = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '1', '2', '1', '2', '1', 'l', '1', '3', '4', '2', '1', '2', '1', '1', '2', '1', '1', '6', '4', '3', '2', '2']

    root = Tk()
    ex = Game(root)

    def add_number_to_screen():
        global tile_frame_column_counter
        global tiles_make_number_counter
        global tile_frame_column
        global xpos
        global ypos

        if not tile_numbers:
            return

        rand = random.choice(tile_numbers)
        tile_frame_column[tile_frame_column_counter] = Button(root, text=rand, font="Helvetica 16 bold")

        tile_frame_column[tile_frame_column_counter].place(x=xpos, y=ypos)
        tile_numbers.remove(rand)  # remove that tile from list of tiles
        xpos += 80
        if (len(tiles_make_number) % 7 == 0) & (len(tiles_make_number) > 0):
            xpos = 35
            ypos += 80
            tile_frame_column[tile_frame_column_counter].place(x=xpos, y=ypos)
            xpos += 80
            tiles_make_number[tiles_make_number_counter] = rand
            tile_frame_column_counter += 1
            tiles_make_number_counter += 1
            root.after(10, add_number_to_screen)

    root.after(10, add_number_to_screen)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I want the main() function to be initialized though. Whenever a game object is created I want it to automatically add the main function -- meaning add numbers to the screen. I think the way my code is now, when a game object is created it only creates the screen. There must be a better way to maintain this code though. Also is there a better way to write this code so I don't need all these global variables?

I tried redoing the code like this but it doesn't work:

```
from Tkinter import *
import random

class Game(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, background="white")
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.title("Centered window")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.centerWindow()
        **self.main()**

    def centerWindow(self):

        w = 850
        h = 530

        sw = self.parent.winfo_screenwidth()
        sh = self.parent.winfo_screenheight()

        x = (sw - w)/2
        y = (sh - h)/2
       self.parent.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))

    **def main(self):**

        global tile_frame_column  # the labels that go on the screen of individual numbers
        tile_frame_column = {}

        global tiles_make_number  # dictionary of all the individual numbers
        tiles_make_number = {}

        global tile_frame_column_counter
        tile_frame_column_counter=0

        global tiles_make_number_counter
        tiles_make_number_counter=0

        global xpos
        xpos=35

        global ypos
        ypos=50

        tile_numbers = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '1', '2', '1', '2', '1', 'l', '1', '3', '4', '2', '1', '2', '1', '1', '2', '1', '1', '6', '4', '3', '2', '2']

        root = Tk()
        ex = Game(root)

        def add_number_to_screen():
            global tile_frame_column_counter
            global tiles_make_number_counter
            global tile_frame_column
            global xpos
            global ypos

            if not tile_numbers:
                return

            rand = random.choice(tile_numbers)
            tile_frame_column[tile_frame_column_counter] = Button(root, text=rand, font="Helvetica 16 bold")

            tile_frame_column[tile_frame_column_counter].place(x=xpos, y=ypos)
            tile_numbers.remove(rand)  # remove that tile from list of tiles
            xpos += 80
            if (len(tiles_make_number) % 7 == 0) & (len(tiles_make_number) > 0):
                xpos = 35
                ypos += 80
                tile_frame_column[tile_frame_column_counter].place(x=xpos, y=ypos)
                xpos += 80
            tiles_make_number[tiles_make_number_counter] = rand
            tile_frame_column_counter += 1
            tiles_make_number_counter += 1
            root.after(10, add_number_to_screen)

        root.after(10, add_number_to_screen)
        root.mainloop()
```

All I changed was I added self.main() to the constructor, put main(self) in class Game and removed the " if *name* = '*main*' section. But when I run the program nothing happens. Anybody have suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: Is your problem ~ how to organise code?

Comment: in a nutshell, that is my problem. But it's a little more than that.

Comment: anybody able to help?

Comment: Global statements in top-level code, as you have, has no effect. I recommend you remove them as they are just extra noise.  Global statement within a function, such as add_number_to_screen, are needed *if*, but only if, you rebind the names within the function.

Comment: Take a look at my code now. I changed a lot and improved the code. But another problem remains. Please let me know if you can help

Answer (score -1):

This link would help you : http://sebsauvage.net/python/gui/

It explains how to build properly a GUI with `python` `TkInter` and `wxPython` and will respond precisely to your questions.

In short it's best to make your class inherit from Tkinter.Tk and start the main loop under the `if __name__ == "__main__":` test.

Comment: I did that but some more issues remain. Are you able to help?

Comment: Explain the issues, we'll see.